# Wait for a function to finish before continuing in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, repository-pattern

What I trying to do is to make the `save` method to wait for `this.collection.create()` before executing the save because otherwise it might crash.

```
class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.collection = this.db.collection('users');
        this.collection.create().then(res => {
            if (res.code === 200)
            {
                // collection successfully created
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err.code === 409)
            {
                // collection already exists
            }
        });
    }
}

class BaseRepository<T>
{
  protected db: Database = Container.get('db');
  protected collection: DocumentCollection;

  public save(model: T): void
  {
    this.collection.save(model);
  }
}
```

And then I can use it like this:

```
const userRepository = new UserRepository();
userRepository.save(new User('username', 'password'));
```

I can think of two solutions

1. Run `this.collection.create()` synchronously
2. Create a property called `isCollectionReady` and make a small loop in `save` method that wait for `isCollectionReady` value to change to true.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: You need to read a lot about asynchronous operations in Javascript, the event-driven single threaded nature of node.js, promises and then maybe the use of `async` and `await`.  In Javascript you don't really "wait for a function to finish".  Instead, you use a promise or callback to be notified when it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely don't use a loop; JavaScript is single-threaded, and the async event will never complete.

You can store off the Promise for the initialization instead and simply chain onto it:

```
class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.collection = this.db.collection('users');
        this._initPromise = this.collection.create().then(res => {
            if (res.code === 200)
            {
                // collection successfully created
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err.code === 409)
            {
                // collection already exists
            }
        });
    }

    ensureInitialized() {
        return this._initPromise;
    }
}

class BaseRepository<T>
{
  protected db: Database = Container.get('db');
  protected collection: DocumentCollection;

  public ensureInitialized() {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  public save(model: T): Promise<void>
  {
    return this.ensureInitialized()
      .then(() => this.collection.save(model));
  }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my similar answer, this one is much cleaner